# iOS: How to use LaunchScreen.storyboard for multiple screen sizes?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I use to have a launch screen image for every screen size, and the image differs from iPhone to iPad.
The image also is optimized to look perfect on any screen, because the launch screen USED TO have the possibility to put image for each size.

But Now that it is deprecated. We have to use `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and I don't know how to achieve the same thing with it!

How can I use this "good for nothing" storyboard to show different image for every device out there (iPhone, iPad, Portrait, Landscape). And why isn't this documented at Apple's ?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you can still use launch images but they are deprecated and will stop working at some point. If you have a single image on a coloured background then then [new info.plist](https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/launch-screen/) keys may help. If you want an edge to edge image then you may need to accept some scaling and/or cropping on different devices. Remember that 99% of the time the user won't even see the launch screen as app launches are very fast on modern devices. You may want to consider using the initial viewcontroller as your "launch" screen if you really want the user to see it.

Comment: So I should just use a colored background instead of a real image! what makes me angry is that Apple changed this and provided no explanation on how should migrate from that to this, and everybody is just using a centered logo with colored background.

Comment: Apples guidelines are that the launch screen should simply be the initial view of your apps UI. This is somewhat more difficult to achieve with SwiftUI but relatively easy with UIKit. As I said, most of the time the launch screen isn't even shown. You may want to consider programming your first view to be your "splash" screen with a tap handler to quickly move on to the real app UI.

Comment: It's funny that I was putting an image of the first view as the splash screen so user wouldn't notice. but I was told to change it. and the app takes a moment to launch, so most of the time the image will show up for a sec.
I think the best use of it, is to put an animation there like they did on Tinder.
Thanks for the relay.